# Upload media/images on aws3 using tinymce editor in React js

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, tinymce, rich-text-editor

I'm trying to implement TinyMCE rich text editor in react, all the setup is done. I don't know how can I upload media/images on AWS-3 using TinyMCE in react. If anybody has done it before please share

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, TinyMCE does not upload images on the server. It converts them into base64 and adds them as blobs. To upload these images to the server, you will need to set up [automatic_uploads](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/file-image-upload/#automatic_uploads) and add a custom upload handler (check other options in the configuration reference, like [images_upload_url](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/file-image-upload/#images_upload_url), [images_upload_base_path](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/file-image-upload/#images_upload_base_path), [images_upload_credentials](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/file-image-upload/#images_upload_credentials), etc).

Since `automatic_uploads` isn't one of the default options for React, you will need to set up the additional editor options via [init](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/react-ref/#init).